# Syntax Errors when Calculating Azimuth with Python in Arcgis 10

Tags: python

I'm trying to calcuate an azimuth with Python in arcgis 10, but am getting syntax errors.  Here is my code:

```py
def CalculaAzimuth(Linea):
    Xorigen = linea.firstPoint.Y
    Yorigen = linea.firstPoint.X
    Xfinal = linea.lastPoint.X
    Yfinal = linea.lastPoint.Y
    DeltaX = Xfinal - Xorigen
    DeltaY = Yfinal - Xorigen
    PI = math.pi()
    Azimuth = 4 * PI
    if DeltaX = 0:
        if DeltaY >=0:
            Azimuth = 0
        else:
            Azimuth = 180
    elif DeltaX >0:
        Azimuth = 90 - math.atan( DeltaY / DeltaX ) * 180 / PI
    elif DeltaX <0:
        Azimuth = 270 - math.atan( DeltaY / DeltaX )* 180 / PI

return Azimuth
```

Comment: Hi!  Could you please post what errors you are getting?

Comment: equality checks use == not =

Comment: return should be indented from def statement and not at same level

Comment: You have Linea capitalized in your function definition, but then use linea lowercase in your function block. I would change to lowercase in your function definition: def CalculaAzimuth(linea):

Comment: Also, it is math.pi, not math.pi(). It is a property of math, not a function. I'll post an answer incorporating all of these (with a little cleanup).

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here's a cleaned up version with all the comments above plus a small change in the logic and some variable cleanup.
Note that this is not a true azimuth on a spheroid.

```
def CalculaAzimuth(linea):
    if (hasattr(linea,'type') and linea.type == 'polyline'):
        xf = linea.firstPoint.X
        yf = linea.firstPoint.Y
        xl = linea.lastPoint.X
        yl = linea.lastPoint.Y
        dX = xl - xf
        dY = yl - yf
        PI = math.pi
        Azimuth = 0 #Default case, dX = 0 and dY >= 0
        if dX > 0:
            Azimuth = 90 - math.atan( dY / dX ) * 180 / PI
        elif dX < 0:
            Azimuth = 270 - math.atan( dY / dX )* 180 / PI
        elif dY < 0:
            Azimuth = 180
        return Azimuth
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: To clarify, the above code must be entered in the `Pre-Logic Script Code:` box and CalculaAzimuth(!Shape!) must be entered into the `Expression` box